# Не проходит SQL запрос на создание таблицы

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Вот такой запрос делю в SQL phpmyadmin

```
CREATE TABLE internet_magazin_sales
(
id INT(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
rng VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
rngid VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'noting',
name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
image VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'noting',
text LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
sst INT(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
)
```

но мне выдает почему то:

```
Статический анализ:

Найдено 3 ошибок при анализе.

A symbol name was expected! (near "name" at position 167)
Неожиданное начало выражения. (near "255" at position 180)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "NOT NULL" at position 185)
```

не могу понять что не так до этого кучу таблиц так создал, почему ругается именно на это?

Comment: *почему ругается именно на это?* Изучайте: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-N

Comment: @Akina погодите но ведь раньше можно было! я в этом же проекте кучу таблиц создал где name используется как название столбца

Comment: @Akina а вообще странно - пока ждал ответа тут всё само заработало - видимо просто был какой то глюк сервера и ПМА

Comment: Ну сервер тут вообще не при чём (если мы о MySQL-сервере) - он не делает статических анализов и не шлёт процитированных сообщений. Это явно PHP-который-админ такое пишет.